# JMX doesn't work in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, symmetricds

I have the following configuration: 
I deployed a sample SymmetricDS engine in Tomcat 8. It should have a JMX MBean I have to connect to. The configuration file `symmetric-server.properties` has the following values:

```
# Enable Java Management Extensions (JMX) web console.
#
jmx.http.enable=true

# Port number for Java Management Extensions (JMX) web console.
#
jmx.http.port=31417

# Enable Java Management Extensions (JMX) remote agent.
#
jmx.agent.enable=true

# Port number for the Java Management Extensions (JMX) remote agent.
#
jmx.agent.port=31418
```

And yet when I go to `localhost:31417` I get 404 and when I launch the `JConsole` this application is nowhere to be found.

But when I start SymmetricDS with command `bin\sym` and it launches using the embedded `jetty` server, I can see the `HTTP Adaptor` on `localhost:31417` and can connect via `JConsole` to the local application, yet I cannot connect remotely to `localhost:31418`:

[image]

I downloaded the sources of the SymmetricDS and in the file

```
symmetric-server\src\main\java\org\jumpmind\symmetric\SymmetricWebServer.java
```

there are only three configuguration taken from file `symmetric-server.properties` -- from default values it seems that they are **jmx.http.port** for `HTTP Adaptor`, **https.port** for `HTTPS` and **http.port** for SymmetricWebServer.

I also tried changing `jmx.agent.enable` to `false` and manually overriding java command line options in `sym_service.conf` by adding:

```
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.14=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=31417
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.16=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

to no avail.

Could you please help me, what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

After greping sources I found `SystemConstants.java`, in which again there were ports for **http**, **https** and **jmx.http**, but none for **remote agent**

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you telnet to localhost 31417?

Comment: Did you mean 31418? Because I can not only telnet 31417 -- I see a webpage on that port with `MX4J HTTP Adaptor`. As to 31418 -- no, I cannot telnet to it.

Comment: Yea, I got the port mistyped, sorry. If you cannot telnet to it, that tends to indicate a firewall block.

Comment: My firewall is so turned off that Windows remindes me about it every day, so it should be something else